# Cannot read protected DVDs on shell / headless system

Tags: debian, debian-jessie

Can anybody help me? I'm trying to get access to read protected DVDs for hours now. Attaching USB drive to a Windows PC works fine - all DVDs can be read, also inside an Xubuntu virtual machine on the related host all is fine. But when installing OpenMediaVault as host system, I can read only non-protected DVDs. Because it works 100% inside a guest it's not hardware related.

```
# uname -a
Linux nas 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux


# dpkg -l libdvdread4 libdvdcss2 libdvdnav4
Gewünscht=Unbekannt/Installieren/R=Entfernen/P=Vollständig Löschen/Halten
| Status=Nicht/Installiert/Config/U=Entpackt/halb konFiguriert/
         Halb installiert/Trigger erWartet/Trigger anhängig
|/ Fehler?=(kein)/R=Neuinstallation notwendig (Status, Fehler: GROSS=schlecht)
||/ Name                                        Version                    Architektur                Beschreibung
+++-===========================================-==========================-==========================-====================================
ii  libdvdcss2:amd64                            1.4.0-1~local              amd64                      library for accessing encrypted DVDs
ii  libdvdnav4:amd64                            5.0.1-1                    amd64                      DVD navigation library
ii  libdvdread4:amd64                           5.0.0-1                    amd64                      library for reading DVDs


# dmesg
[ 3184.701656] usb 3-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 3196.173818] usb 3-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 3196.272569] usb 3-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2571
[ 3196.272579] usb 3-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3196.272586] usb 3-1.1: Product: SLIM Portable Blu-ray Drive
[ 3196.272591] usb 3-1.1: Manufacturer: HLDS Inc.
[ 3196.272597] usb 3-1.1: SerialNumber: PROLIFICMP000000376
[ 3196.273202] usb-storage 3-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3196.273564] scsi8 : usb-storage 3-1.1:1.0
[ 3197.397138] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST BD-RE BP55EB40   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 3197.486298] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[ 3197.486731] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 3197.487181] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 5
[ 3216.362379] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0]
[ 3216.362388] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 3216.362392] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0]
[ 3216.362396] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 3216.362402] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0]
[ 3216.362408] Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[ 3216.362413] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB:
[ 3216.362416] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 02 00
[ 3216.362429] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 4096
[ 3216.362514] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 512
[ 3216.427062] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0]
[ 3216.427069] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 3216.427074] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0]
[ 3216.427077] Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 3216.427083] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0]
[ 3216.427089] Add. Sense: Read of scrambled sector without authentication
[ 3216.427094] sr 8:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB:
[ 3216.427096] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 02 00
[ 3216.427110] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 4096
[ 3216.427195] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 512


# udevadm info /dev/sr0
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.1/3-1.1:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/block/sr0
N: sr0
L: -100
S: cdrom
S: cdrw
S: disk/by-id/usb-HL-DT-ST_BD-RE_BP55EB40_PROLIFICMP000000376-0:0
S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:16.0-usb-0:1.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
S: dvd
S: dvdrw
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-HL-DT-ST_BD-RE_BP55EB40_PROLIFICMP000000376-0:0 /dev/dvd /dev/cdrom /dev/cdrw /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:16.0-usb-0:1.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 /dev/dvdrw
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sr0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.1/3-1.1:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/block/sr0
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_CDROM=1
E: ID_CDROM_BD=1
E: ID_CDROM_BD_R=1
E: ID_CDROM_BD_RE=1
E: ID_CDROM_CD=1
E: ID_CDROM_CD_R=1
E: ID_CDROM_CD_RW=1
E: ID_CDROM_DVD=1
E: ID_CDROM_DVD_PLUS_R=1
E: ID_CDROM_DVD_PLUS_RW=1
E: ID_CDROM_DVD_PLUS_R_DL=1
E: ID_CDROM_DVD_R=1
E: ID_CDROM_DVD_RAM=1
E: ID_CDROM_DVD_RW=1
E: ID_CDROM_MEDIA=1
E: ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD=1
E: ID_CDROM_MEDIA_SESSION_COUNT=1
E: ID_CDROM_MEDIA_STATE=complete
E: ID_CDROM_MEDIA_TRACK_COUNT=1
E: ID_CDROM_MEDIA_TRACK_COUNT_DATA=1
E: ID_CDROM_MRW=1
E: ID_CDROM_MRW_W=1
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=block-pci-0000_00_16_0-usb-0_1_1_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
E: ID_INSTANCE=0:0
E: ID_MODEL=BD-RE_BP55EB40
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=BD-RE\x20BP55EB40\x20\x20
E: ID_MODEL_ID=2571
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:16.0-usb-0:1.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_16_0-usb-0_1_1_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
E: ID_REVISION=1.00
E: ID_SERIAL=HL-DT-ST_BD-RE_BP55EB40_PROLIFICMP000000376-0:0
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=PROLIFICMP000000376
E: ID_TYPE=cd
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=HL-DT-ST
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=HL-DT-ST
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=067b
E: MAJOR=11
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: TAGS=:systemd:uaccess:seat:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=3195163408
```

As you can see, for these read-protected video DVDs there is no `ID_FS_TYPE` and `ID_FS_LABEL` returned. What's the reason for this all?

---

It seems, that these `scrambled sector` errors appear in different distributions as long as you didn't access the DVD by a movie player which itself uses `libdvdcss` for access. I've setup Debian and Ubuntu a lot of times now and my last tests show, that an `Ubuntu 16.04 Server` is able to show the `ID_FS_LABEL/TYPE` informations from copy protected DVDs, but `Debian 8.6` isn't.

What's the difference between those two Linux distributions that one works while another don't?

Comment: One thing I do know is that some protected game DVDs cannot be read or mounted in windows if the DVD device is in PIO mode. Perhaps this is useful for tracking down the difference?

Comment: @rabudde I have exactly the same problem. Did you figure out a solution for this?

Comment: @TylerDurden No, I've used Ubuntu since then.

Comment: @rabudde I solved using `dd` and `blkid` as outlined here [https://b3n.org/automatic-ripping-machine/](). Search for a post of Reinhard (December 8, 2016 at 6:36 am). I can put that down as answer if you like.

Comment: @TylerDurden : That might be (or, have been) a good idea, since the link is broken.