# Debian: udevadm info does not return ID_FS_TYPE for DVD-media

Tags: linux, debian, debian-jessie, udev

On Debian Jessie (openmediavault) the following command:

`udevadm info -q env -n /dev/sr0`

Does not return `ID_FS_TYPE` for a movie-dvd. The packages `libdvdcss2` and `libdvdread4` are installed.

Update:
This post is related: [Cannot read protected DVDs on shell / headless system](https://superuser.com/q/1153874/651639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess: ID_FS_* is not reported because it can't mount the encrypted filesystem. libdvdcss does allow to *read* the DVD from userspace, but not to *mount* it: that would need the code in the kernel, with all the legal problems that implies.

*Why* do you need `ID_FS_TYPE` in the first place? Very likely your actual problem can be solved without `ID_FS_TYPE`.

Comment: I was using it to build up my media library using a script. I worked around it using `dd` and `blkid` to get the type and label but I was wondering. The DVD actually just mounts fine...

Comment: Solved it by the workaround outlined here by user Reinhard: https://b3n.org/automatic-ripping-machine/ using `dd` to extract the first 514K and then get more info using `blkid`.